# Multiple Polylines Using an Array of LatLng values

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, i'm trying to do real time tracking using Google Maps API V3 and draw Multiple Polylines on maps using Array of LatLng Coordinates, below is the code which i am using:

```
var caseinfo = new Array();
caseinfo.push("V 28.5549 77.1919");
caseinfo.push("H1 28.561012 77.161527 28.561024 77.162429 28.561024 77.164129");
caseinfo.push("H2 28.551024 77.163129 28.365241 77.025134 28.3662158 77.025134");
var i, j, k;
var splitinfo = [];
for(i = 0 ; i < caseinfo.length ; i++) {
       splitinfo[i] = caseinfo[i].split(" ");
       alert(splitinfo[i]);
}
var polyline =new Array();
for(i = 0 ; i < splitinfo.length() ; i++) {
    polyline.push([]);
    for(j = 1 ; j < splitinfo[i].length ; j = j + 2) {
         polyline[i].push(new google.map.LatLng(polyline[i][j], polyline[i][j + 1]));
    }
}
alert(polyline);
```

I wanted polyline to look like this `[[(28.5549,77.1919)],[(28.561012,77.161527),(28.561024,77.162429),(28.560124,77.164129)],[(28.551024,77.163129),(28.365241,77.025134),(28.3662158,77.025134)]]` so that I can draw three polylines by setting the path as `polyine[i]`.

Can someone please help me! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2G8SK/)

1. arrays have .length properties, MVCArrays have .length() methods, use the appropriate one
2. polyline doesn't have anything in it here:

   polyline[i].push(new google.map.LatLng(polyline[i][j], polyline[i][j + 1]));

You want that to be "splitinfo".

Updated code:

```
var caseinfo = new Array();
caseinfo.push("V 28.5549 77.1919");
caseinfo.push("H1 28.561012 77.161527 28.561024 77.162429 28.561024 77.164129");
caseinfo.push("H2 28.551024 77.163129 28.365241 77.025134 28.3662158 77.025134");
var i, j, k;
var splitinfo = [];
for (i = 0; i < caseinfo.length; i++) {
    splitinfo[i] = caseinfo[i].split(" ");
    // alert(splitinfo[i]);
}
var polyline = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < splitinfo.length; i++) {
    polyline.push([]);
    for (j = 1; j < splitinfo[i].length; j = j + 2) {
        polyline[i].push(new google.maps.LatLng(splitinfo[i][j], splitinfo[i][j + 1]));
    }
    var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polyline[i],
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    path.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, it works well. Also, can u suggest some reference link from where i can learn Javascript and Google Map API. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you shouldn't use "length()." length is an attribute, not a function. You use it correctly elsewhere.

Also "google.map.LatLng" should be "google.maps.LatLng"

Viewing the console in your browser when you try to run this will help you spot errors such as these.

Comment: @KadeKeith You might want to take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead then (Basically, we understand that you can't comment yet, but that doesn't automatically make posting it as an answer okay)

Comment: @DennisMeng Is identifying errors in the code not an appropriate answer to the question? "Can someone please help me! ?" This seems to fall under the answering guidelines found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer. Specifically "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful"

Comment: I was speaking more in response to "Considering I do not have sufficient reputation to comment I did not have any other option".

Comment: If not length function then what other can i use ?

Comment: Thanks @kadekeith, i'll try using the correct functions next time.